# Determine whether the series is converges or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\right)$$

The question is to determine whether the series converges or diverges. I’ve tried to use the integral test but I couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: Hint: try multiplying each term by$$\frac{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: @user744868 :I still don't get it, after multiplications , i got root n divided by the denominators that I used for multiplication, then what method can  I used next?

Comment: Now, divide top and bottom by $\sqrt{n}$, and note that the expression does not tend to $0$. What does this tell you?

Comment: @user744868 :then I got 1/(1+the root of (1+n^(-1/2))), thus as n goes to infinity, the term will be convergence

Comment: The terms do converge, but to $1/2$. It doesn't converge to $0$. When you add up infinitely many terms, each of which are approximately $1/2$, the series diverges.

Comment: @user744868 :ok thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

As we workshopped in the comments,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n} &= \frac{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n}}{1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\left(\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}}^2 - \sqrt{n}^2}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{1/\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n + \sqrt{n}}{n}} + 1} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} + 1} \\
&\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 0} + 1} = \frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$. If the series converged, then we would have the terms converge to $0$. Since this is not the case, the series must diverge.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left(\sqrt n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = n + \sqrt n + \frac{1}{4}  $$
which suggests that
$$ \sqrt{n + \sqrt n} \approx \sqrt n + \frac{1}{2}  $$

To confirm,.
$$ \left(\sqrt n + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8 \sqrt n}  \right)^2 = n + \sqrt n  - \frac{1}{8 \sqrt n}  + \frac{1}{64n} < n + \sqrt n$$
so
$$ \sqrt n + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8 \sqrt n}   <  \sqrt{n + \sqrt n} < \sqrt n + \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1+1/√n)^{1/2}=$

$1+(1/2)(1/√n)+O(1/n);$

$a_n: =√n(\sqrt{1+1/√n}-1)=√n((1/2)(1/√n)+O(1/n))=$

$1/2 +O(1/√n)$;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \not =0$, $\sum a_n$ does converge.

Answer (score 0):

You already received good answers showing that it diverges.

We also can *approximate* the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\right)$$ By Taylor expansion for large $n$, we have 
$$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}=\frac12-\frac 1{8 \sqrt n}+\frac 1{16 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ Using generalized harmonic numbers, we then have
$$S_p=\frac p2-\frac 1{8}H_p^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\frac 1{16 }H_p +\cdots$$
Using asymptotics
$$S_p\sim \frac{p}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{p}}{4}+\frac 1{16 }\log(p)+\frac{1}{16} \left(\gamma -2 \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+\cdots$$ and we could even ignore the constant terms which is small $(0.21862)$.

For illustration purposes, let us compute $S_{100}$. Using Excel or Wolfram Alpha, you shoud find a value of $47.9346$ while the above formula would give $48.0005$.